# маршрутизация с хост машины на виртуалки

Tags: сеть, администрирование

На хостмашине настроил 2 провайдера для 2ух интерфейсов.

На одном интерфейсе eno1 серый ip, 192.168.2.110

На втором интерфейсе eno2 белый ip, 58.xxx.xxx.246

По ssh могу подключится к хостмашине(через белый и серый ip), а к виртуалкам у хостмашины могу подключиться только через белый ip, через серый не идет. Хотя судя по пакетам, они доходят, но не возвращаются.

Вот результат iptables -L -v -n -t nat

Через eno2 захожу, через eno1 нет.

```
    8   452 DNAT       tcp  --  eno1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10422 to:10.0.0.104:22
   18  1072 DNAT       tcp  --  eno2   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10422 to:10.0.0.104:22
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? На роутере маршрут настроил для серого ip 192.168.2.110 порта 10422. По идее должен заходить без проблем. Может нужно делать пост роутинг или что еще? в сетевом администрировании не селен. 
Больше спасибо.

Comment: Вроде разобрался, сейчас добавлю все в автостарт, ребутнусь, проверю, напишу :)

Comment: Разобрался, ну не совсем.
после добавление основного шлюза

route add default gw 192.168.2.1 eno1

могу заходить на виртуалки с хост машины по серому ip, но по белому пропадает доступ.

Если у кого есть идеи как это решить, подскажите пожалуйста.